# Use all 255 server IP Addresses

Tags: ubuntu, php, ip, curl

I am running an Ubuntu server having 255 IP addresses. I want to write down a PHP script that uses each IP to do a curl request. Is this possible ?

Comment: late but why do you have a /24 on 1 Server???

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Depends on the nature of the networking as far as your server is concerned, and what it would be connecting to.

In most cases, you'll lose two addresses out of a full 256 octet - one for the network address (192.168.21.0) and one for the broadcast address (192.168.21.255). Remember that you'll also need a router in the same local subnet (192.168.21.1), so you're down to 253. (Assuming this is a CIDR/24 network).

Curl has a --interface option - you can use this to specify which IP your request is coming from; you may want to consider writing in this in perl or something not web-oriented - might make it a bit easier.

Here's hoping you're not stuffing ballot boxes.